# Vaading 14.6.4's Multi-Select Combobox cannot have items added to the list if it was created in Vaadin Designer

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

When using https://vaadin.com/directory/component/multiselect-combo-box/2.5.0 in Vaadin 14.6.4 *and* using it (ie creating it) in Vaadin Designer, I've discovered that the multi-select combo box does NOT obey any java code that adds items to the list. (This problem disappears if the multi-select combo box is INSTANTIATED in Java code itself and then added to a layout.) Any easy fixes/workarounds?

Comment: I would say instantiating the component in Java code would be the easy fix / workaround?

Comment: What does "does NOT obey any java code" mean? Please add said code (and maybe also the manual code that works) and how you added/bound the component.